# Create AWS Name tag based off last octet of private IP Terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to use *count* to create a number of instances in terraform. The way our IPA works is that it attaches the last octet of the private IP address right before the '.fdqn' of the name tag. I would like to have the IPA-name tag created to match the name IPA gives the instance. I have tried a few variations of the following.

```
resource "aws_instance" "test-instance" {
  count         = 3
  ami           = lookup(var.ami,var.aws_region)
  instance_type = var.instance_type
  key_name      = "Default_AWS_Key"

  tags = {
    name = "test-.fdqn"
    IPA-Name = format("test-%s.fdqn", split(".", aws_instance.test-instance[index.count].private_ip))

  }
}
```

Comment: You can't do this because `private_ip` is not known until after the instance is created, so it can't be used *for* the creation. You will need a way to apply tags after the resource is created.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense. I tried marking as answered, but I don't think I have control of the question anymore.